# Silverlight - Layout Question

Tags: silverlight

I am creating a Silverlight application that should take up the width of the user's screen. This application has a horizontal row that greets the user. Then, two columns below it. The right column is always a fixed size. I want the left column to take up any remaining space. In an attempt to accomplish this, I am using the following XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="layoutRoot" Background="White">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid x:Name="greetingGrid" Margin="0,0,0,8">            
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="Welcome " />
      <TextBlock x:Name="usernameTextBlock" />
    </StackPanel>            
  </Grid>    

  <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Grid.Row="1">            
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="leftGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <Border x:Name="leftBorder" BorderBrush="Black" Height="250">
        <!-- Insert Wrap Panel of Images --!>
      </Border>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="rightGrid" Width="100" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,0,0,0">
      <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <TextBlock Text="How would you like to view the images?" />
      <ComboBox x:Name="optionComboBox">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Name" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Date" />
      </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Oddly, the two lower columns are split evenly in size. How do I make the left column take up all remaining space?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition width="*" />
  <ColumnDefinition width="250"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Use * for the grid column to take the rest of the available space. Keep in mind that the parent container also needs to take the whole area to make it work!

Comment: My problem is that the "rightGrid" Width value is animated. Because it is animated, this approach does not work. I added "100" as a placeholder.

Comment: I got it! I made the width of the second ColumnDefinition "auto".  Thank you!

Comment: +1 But the meaning of * is a little deeper.  First of all think of is as "1*".  Other Columns or Rows may also define "1*" or "2*" or "3*" etc.  The sum of all the co-efficients of * are taken.  The "rest of the available" space is divided by this sum and that effectively becomes the value of *.  Each Row or Column will get its N* proportion of the available space.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the widths of the columns rather than on your "rightGrid", eg:

```
    <Grid x:Name="greetingGrid" Margin="0,0,0,8">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Welcome " />
            <TextBlock x:Name="usernameTextBlock" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100px" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="leftGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Fuchsia">
            <Border x:Name="leftBorder" BorderBrush="Black" Height="250">

  </Border>
</Grid>

<Grid x:Name="rightGrid"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,0,0,0">
  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  <TextBlock Text="How would you like to view the images?" />
  <ComboBox x:Name="optionComboBox">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Name" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Date" />
  </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</Grid>
```